# How To Solve [Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect]?

Tags: php, apache, function, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to check that my server **Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS** is online or not at my shared hosting server. My server has IP not domain but my shared hosting server has domain. For this purpose I used the below code in my shared hosting server to check that my server is online or not.

```
<?php
$site = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
$port = 7550;
$fp = fsockopen($site,$port,$errno,$errstr,10);
if ($fp === false) { 
 print($errno." : ".$errstr); 
}  
if(!$fp)
{
echo "SERVER IS DOWN";
}
else
{
echo "SERVER IS UP ON PORT ".$port." AT ".$site;
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

After adding the above code in my shared hosting server php file, when I run it then I got the below error.

`Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to XX.XX.XX.XX:7550 (Connection timed out) in /home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php on line 4 110 : Connection timed out SERVER IS DOWN`

Now somebody tell me to check that `allow_url_fopen = On` is turn on in my shared hosting server or not then I checked my shared hosting server `php.ini` file and there it is turn on.

Now as I was looking for help all around then somebody else told me to check both(my shared hosting server and my server) have `fsockopen()` ON or not. Then I wrote the below code in a php file and run on both servers.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen ("localhost", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
echo "$errstr ($errno)
\n";
}else
{
echo "fsockopen Is Working Perfectly.";
}
fclose ($fp);
?>
```

After running the above .php file on both servers then I got the below result same on both server.

`fsockopen Is Working Perfectly.`

Important Note: Keep in mind that my server IP remain active as I am using many PC on that IP but my server is turn off. Also I am able to open `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550` in my Web-Browser using proxy.

Comment: `Connection timed out` usually points to a firewall or an answer from the remote side that just takes too long.

Comment: Are you sure your firewall correctly forwarded tcp port 7550 on the target server? Because usually a webserver is running in port 80 which is open ofcourse opened if you can enter websites.

Comment: @Steini I am able to open `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550` in my Web-Browser using proxy.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I know whats the meaning of `Connection timed out` but I open `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550` on proxy then it is taking only 1 sec to open in browser.

Comment: If you want network communication with advanced functionality, use `socket_create` instead of `fsockopen`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I am a newbie in this field. So can you share the whole code in answer. I got all above codes in question from internet.

Comment: I don't get paid coding for stackoverflow questions. You should read [the documentation](http://php.net/socket_create) and learn from it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks for your time for mentioning the link.

Answer (score 7):

Because **`fsockopen`** throws a `E_WARNING` exception if hostname is not a valid domain. So, you use a IP with a PORT **offline** then the function throws the exception.

You can solve with handle the exception or **@**:

```
$fp = @fsockopen($site,$port,$errno,$errstr,10);
```

If you think that you PORT is online, check the firewall and after check with a external resouce like http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.

Read http://php.net/manual/es/function.fsockopen.php.

**UPDATED:**
You could test with **`socket_create`**, it's better that `fosockopen`.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$connection =  @socket_connect($socket, 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 7550);

if( $connection ){
    echo 'ONLINE';
} else {
    echo 'OFFLINE: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error( $socket ));
}
```

You must set a valid protocol, see: http://php.net/manual/es/function.socket-create.php.

Comment: Suppressing error message with @ doesn't solve problems. It just creates new ones.

Comment: No. If you need check if a port is online in a IP (and not in a domain) you need handle the exception or use the `@`. If you handle exception then you will need the `if` condition and `try, catch`.
Read http://php.net/manual/es/function.fsockopen.php. **Show errors in a production environment is bad**.

Comment: @Snake I am able to open `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550` in my Web-Browser using proxy and also your link is showing that my `7550` port is open.

Comment: @Snake When I added `$fp = @fsockopen($site,$port,$errno,$errstr,10);` then I got `110 : Connection timed out SERVER IS DOWN`... :(

Comment: Can you open a socket to other IP or domain? The first is identify the problem. (Obviously with `fsockopen`)
Have you tested with `socket_create`?

Comment: @Snake I am new in this field. So I didn't try any other codes for this also I got all above codes in question from internet. Can you share any new codes?

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan, have you tested with other address? So we could know if the problem is with fsockopen. **I have updated my answer with `socket_create` method**.

Comment: @Snake After adding your new updated code, I got `OFFLINE: Connection timed out` yet my server is on and working in browser...

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan Have you seted a valid protocol? It's the last thing I can think of. Perhaps your protocol is UDP (I don't know) so you must set SOL_UDP instead of SOL_TCP.

Comment: @Snake After changing `SOL_UDP` instead of `SOL_TCP` in you provided answer code, I got `OFFLINE: Success` text after running the PHP file at my shared hosting server even my **Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS** is online.

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan Is your server port TCP or UDP? If you don't know this you can't connect. I have two negative votes in this answer. So, i can't do anymore :(. It is not a programatic problem, it's a problem with your server and knowledges. Read about [`socket_create`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.socket-create.php) types and protocols. I hope I've helped a little.

Comment: @Snake Helping is not for voting. Anyway I am using `ZTE ZXDSL 831CII` router. I did these setting on my router to open external port and forward it. http://goo.gl/0N8l96 http://goo.gl/PkCfjS http://goo.gl/mxov5a

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I helped you not for voting but my answer is not the correct :). For this, i have two negative votes, i apologize for this. i don't know about your router or connection. I know about LAMP, I'm sorry. I think you must ask about open the ports and put the server online. Regards!

Comment: @Snake Ok then thanks for trying to help me till now. My friends are able to see me on `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550` from the whole world without any VPN so it mean the my ports are open and incoming connection are allowed. (One Vote up from me to try to help me)

Answer (score 2):

If you overwrote the error handler with set `set_error_handler()` you need to check if `error_reporting()` returns 0 which means an @ was used to suppress errors.

```
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {

    if (error_reporting() === 0) 
        return false;

    //handle error
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually shared host ban all port except 80 try port 80

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the problem of pfsockopen(), if this phenomenon occurs during the Apache stress test, you should consider whethter Apache has not turned on the keepalive parameter.