# SMTP not working in Opencart

Tags: php, email, smtp, opencart2.x

I have developed an ecommerce site in opencart. 
In that SMTP mail is not working, Can you please check my settings.

http://ebidrive.com/ocart2/admin/index.php?route=setting/setting&user_token=bJPdx2gTO2bbnY3QPM3txYEoMhOaUVYU

[image]

The mail is not working.

```
Login credentials to open admin panel:    
Username:admin
password:pass
```

Am getting this error

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is username and password to open admin pane? Kindly mention on it.

Comment: *How* is it not working? What happens? What error do you get?

Comment: Kindly check edited question

Comment: Maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305417/how-to-solve-warning-fsockopen-unable-to-connect